# How to use python get F5 configuration DIFF

Tags: config, diff, f5

I'm new to network automation. I was looking at using genie pyat to grab configuration diff from F5. But after some reading and I realised pyat won't support F5.

Apart from using a library like config-diff, is there a better way specific to F5?